# Screen Lock Checks password file but not Active Directory

Tags: password, screen-lock, passwd, shadow

We have a Linux system running Centos 7 and have an issue with the screen lock.  We have a multi-user environment where each user has their own account.  The authentication is using our university active directory.  Only local accounts use the passwd & shadow files and indeed if a local account locks the screen they are able to unlock it.  All other users are authenticated using the AD and get authentication error when they try.

```
We are using sssd.
This from secure log:
Oct 30 08:59:54 b400 kcheckpass[94374]: pam_listfile(kscreensaver:auth): Refused user teach for service kscreensaver
Oct 30 08:59:55 b400 kcheckpass[94374]: pam_sss(kscreensaver:auth): authentication failure; logname=syin uid=1005 euid=1005 tty=:0 ruser= rhost= user=teach
Oct 30 08:59:55 b400 kcheckpass[94374]: pam_sss(kscreensaver:auth): received for user teach: 17 (Failure setting user credentials)
Oct 30 09:00:02 b400 gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by ouidad(uid=0)
Oct 30 09:00:03 b400 polkitd[663]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c243 (system bus name :1.20066 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)

This from messages:
Oct 30 08:59:55 b400 [sssd[krb5_child[94379]]]: Preauthentication failed
Oct 30 08:59:55 b400 [sssd[krb5_child[94379]]]: Preauthentication failed
Oct 30 08:59:55 b400 [sssd[krb5_child[94379]]]: Preauthentication failed
Oct 30 08:59:55 b400 kcheckpass[94374]: Authentication failure for teach (invoked by uid 1005)
```

The sssd logs were either empty or provided no clues.
What can I do to make sure on login it checks against the AD instead of the passwd/shadow files for screen unlocks?

Comment: I don't understand. If a local account locked the screen, only this local account should be able to unlock it, shouldn't it?

Comment: Only our AD users get locked out on screen lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out ... the kscreensaver file located in /etc/pam.d was misconfigured during a recovery update. We had backup files of the kscreensaver configuration file and simply copied using cp command to the original condition before the update.

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
# auth      required      pam_listfile.so file=/etc/allowed.nmr.users item=user sense=allow onerr=fail
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        [default=1 success=ok] pam_localuser.so
auth        [success=done ignore=ignore default=die] pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

```
systemctl rstart sssd
```

We restarted sssd and the unlock function for active directory users was restored.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/316379)

Comment: @Jesse_b: note that this appears to be the OP with a partial answer. 3dalliance: there's no rush to post an answer. Please post Answers as complete answers, so that you don't risk running afoul of conscientious reviewers who might consider a partial answer a non-answer :)  Thanks, all!